# Activate check and reset button after complete all inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

I have 6 input fields and I need to make check and reset buttons active after all inputs were completed.Ill attach a fiddle and some code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/72/)

```
$('.input').on('input', function() {         
  limit();
  checkBtn.disabled = false;
  resetBtn.disabled = false;        
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find empty inputs using a selector. If there are empty inputs, disable buttons; otherwise enable them.

```
$('.input').on('input', function() {         
  if($('input[value=""]').length) {
   checkBtn.attr("disabled", "disabled");
   resetBtn.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    checkBtn.removeAttr('disabled');
    resetBtn.removeAttr('disabled'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Pretty much just a re-write, but I'd suggest instead `$(checkBtn, resetBtn).prop('disabled', $('input[value=""]').length);` in jQuery 1.6+ the `disabled` property should be manipulated using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), rather than `attr()` (although if they're both already jQuery objects it might be wiser *not* to re-wrap them in jQuery and use two separate chains).